# Wine windows and font became large!

Tags: wine

How can I reset wine window and font size to default? Window and font size become so large That I can't use wine window anymore!
This is an example of current window and font size. As you see in it size of everything is so big that just window menu takes all my screen.
[image: Example Screenshot of windows in wine!]

Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file ~/.wine/system.reg in a text editor such as gedit.

There should be an entry about it such as:

```
[System\\CurrentControlSet\\Hardware Profiles\\Current\\Software\\Fonts]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060
```

Then change the value that you see there to 60.

[Source](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=515)

Comment: Giving thanksgiving is against `StackExchange` laws. Anyway  thank you. It solved my problem :).

Comment: I know, but it's a really common answer as the guy from 2008 stated. Don't know what else to say. :p

Let's make that an exception.

You're welcome.

Comment: @SirSaleh It is encouraged to give thanks, but in comments, not as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the correct path @Pilot6 by the way you saved my life way too many times with that RTL8192EU pack. Thanks!

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh! thanks! It was a misunderstanding by me ;)